# Installed some Gnome Shell Extentions with apt (deb package) - Howto enable them?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I did:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-show-ip
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-weather
```

I checked the GUI "Extensions" and "gnome-tweaks" and don't see them in this list. How to enable and configure them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once installed the extensions with those commands, try to restart the gnome-shell by Alt+F2 type `restart` and Press Enter..

[image]

Then open `extensions app` or `tweaks` to control them..

Alternatively logout and logback in is also a way..

I just relogin, once the two commands you mentioned are ran.

[image]